# Wolfram Integration Substituion Step

Tags: probability, integration, variance, wolfram-alpha

I've been quite bizzy with a exercise from Probabilty Theory. As you know when calculating variation you have to calculate with integrals. My calculus hasn't been that good. So, I asked Wolfram to help me. It's been a great help, but it's making a step I really can't explain. 
I found some integrals which look like it, but there the step is somewhat easier to understand.

Given the equation:

$\frac{1}{\pi} \int \frac{\left( u + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - u^2}} du $
How does one end up here?

$ \frac{1}{\pi} \int \left(\frac{\sin(v)}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 dv $

Wolfram tells me that $ u = \frac{\sin(s)}{2}$ and $du = \frac{\cos(s)}{2} $
And this all makes perfect sense to me, but somehow I can only end up with a slightly different form:

$ \frac{1}{\pi} \int \frac{(\sin(v) + \frac{1}{2})^2}{\frac{\cos(v)}{2}}  \frac{1}{2} \cos(v) dv $

How does simplifying this result to the answer Wolfram gives?

Comment: Note that it is $( \frac{\sin(v)}2 + \frac{1}{2})^2$ *not* $(\sin(v) + \frac{1}{2})^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to cancel the cosine factor:
$$
\frac{(\frac{\sin(v)}2 + \frac{1}{2})^2}{ \color{red}{\frac{\cos(v)}{2}}}  \color{red}{\frac{1}{2} \cos(v)}=\left(\frac{\sin(v)}2 + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2.
$$

Comment: Oh, I did my substition wrong. I'm bad at details..

Comment: @RichardDirven If you are Ok with my answer above, please feel free to accept it.